# Unity + ARCORE DllNotFoundException: arcore_unity_api

Tags: arcore

I tried to run the arcore samples for unity as described on the following page: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android

But it doesn't work. The app starts and it is searching for the planes, but the camera feed is black. In the logcat there is the following exception:

```
DllNotFoundException: arcore_unity_api
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager/ExternApi:ArCoreUnity_setArPrestoInitialized (GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager/EarlyUpdateCallback)
  at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARPrestoCallbackManager.InitializeIfNeeded () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GoogleARCoreInternal.ARCoreAndroidLifecycleManager.CreateSession (GoogleARCore.ARCoreSession sessionComponent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GoogleARCore.ARCoreSession.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I also tried the plain android samples, which work fine. What could be the issue that it doesn't work with unity?

Comment: I got the same issue, Building on Unity works, but exporting project, generating an AAR and Importing that AAR on a new project and using an UnityPlayerActivity doesnt display camera image, but shows buttons and snackBar added on Unity Canvas. Got the same error on LogCat. Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I migrated back to Unity 2018.x to 2017.4.6f => now it works

Comment: Does ARcore in 2017.4.6f allow for 64bit builds?

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear, **Unity can't find the ARCore dll.**

If you are using Unity [Assembly Definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)
 (which is a good thing to consider), you need to verify that the ARCore dll is being referenced correctly.

I solved this by **putting a reference in my "main" .asmdef file to the .asmdef file from the ARCore folder** (where the dll file is). (in my case Unity lost this reference by some odd reason)

If you are not using Assembly Definitions (it could be a good time to start), it could be interesting to double-check if you have the ARCore installed correctly in your project and if you have 'ARCore Support' enabled.

**EDIT -> Project Settings (Android Tab) -> XR Settings**, and check the box for "ARCore Supported" (see screenshot)
[image: enabling ARCore support for Android]